# methods of restricting access

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

I've been restricting access to the administrator section of my websites by IP.  My Apache configs include a list of Allow directives that I maintain to let my staff have access.   The maintenance is a bit of a pain, some people don't have fixed IPs (or travel a lot) but I consider this level of security to be strong.

I might need to change my approach.  The first thing that comes to mind is enabling MFA on the admin section of our sites.   Would AWS VPN be a good fit for this problem?   What other techniques should I consider?

Comment: Strong passwords + MFA (U2F/TOTP, not SMS/email, preferably) should be sufficient in most cases. If you're in a regulated field you may need the VPN as well, but I tend to think that's unnecessary for something like a website's web UI.

Comment: VPN is likely overkill. Passwords and MFA is likely sufficient.